# Appropriate tests and normalization approaches for highly non-normal data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, normalization, proportion

I'm trying to ascertain whether a particular type of article, $T$, is associated with higher engagement scores in academic journals, and how substantial the effect size might be. I have raw data of engagement figures for every article published in one year period for 10 different journals. The first thing to note is that the data is highly skewed - most articles get low engagement, some get huge traction. It is not normally distributed, nor does any obvious transform seem to make it so. A histogram from 6872 articles from one journal (shown below) has median engagement 2, mode 1, mean 13.3 and a max of 15984. In this example, there is only one article of the particular type, which just so happens to have the max engagement score. The second highest score for comparison is 2676.

[image]

Secondly, while different journals tend to be broadly similar, some trend higher on engagement in general by virtue of being bigger journals with wider interest. I was thinking that one way of looking at this might be to normalise the data in some way for each journal - for example, the one article of type $T$ accounts for 17.48% of all engagement, while the remaining engagement (82.58%) is shared over the other 6871 articles, yielding an average contribution of 0.012% per article of all other types. While I could in theory do this for each journal, given the highly non-normal nature of the data, I'm not convinced that a typical parametric test would hold - and in each journal, the articles of interest are rare (usually 1-5 per journal year) so does anyone know any good ways to approach this question? Very open to suggestion...

Comment: Very interesting application! What about rank transform / using rank based tests? You could also consider Pareto distribution - it's a bit like income, few high scorers, many "loosers".

Comment: Are trying to test if distributions across article types are different? how many types of articles do you have ? Your data are counts and highly skewed thus normality here is in question.

Comment: Hi @utobi- there are only two types of article in these journals for our purposes - type T (retracted articles) and all others. Our preliminary analysis suggests this former type in our field generate much more public interest prior to their subsequent retraction than others, and we're looking for a means to compare this fairly. In each journal, publications per year range from 500 - 18000, so there's high individual counts but retracted articles are relatively rare (1-5 per journal year). I like the rank idea - public engagement metrics skew extremely, might help.

Comment: If the journals differ much in popularity, you can rank within each journal, with the extra benefit that this normalizes between journals :-). However, if a scandalous article creates public buzz, it might be independent of the journal's average engagement metrics

Comment: Hi @Ute - excellent point! I think I can do a Mann-Whitney U Test, taking all articles from all journals together and comparing the rank of the T type (retracted articles) the to non-retracted ones; if I'm understanding correctly, this would avoid the need to normalise and it would already rank the pooled data..